# Wordpress custom meta box to include background picture

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am designing a WordPress theme and would like to post recipes. The text (ingredients, etc.) will go into the main post window, but I would like to include a picture, which should become the background picture of the whole window. The usual Upload/Insert includes the picture into the post. Is there any better way of associating a picture to a post? Should I use the Custom Fields for this?

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easy i recommend a plugin for that [The Advanced custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Its very easy to use. You can get full documentation [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/getting-started/)

This plugin always save my development time.
Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Check out WP-Alchemy.
http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/

It's incredible.  It can be implemented into a plugin, or a theme.  I have used it and it works great!

Otherwise, the term you are looking for is "Wordpress Custom Meta Box" throw that in google, and you will get more info than you probably wanted.

If you are more of a wordpress codex junkie, check out the add_meta_box function.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box